# Accidentally clicked the wrong review button

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I accidentally tapped 'Looks OK' on this VLQQ item. It wasn't an audit, nor did it finalize anything, but it was the wrong click.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5838832

Anything I can do about this?

If I misclick and 'leave open' while close-voting, I can go to the question and VTC from there, but I don't have 10k to vote to delete outside of review.

---

Ignoring the particular example's merits - **if you do the wrong review action, can you fix it?**

Comment: IMO there is absolutely nothing wrong with the answer.  It provides a correct answer to the question as asked, so the *answer* doesn't need deleted.  However, the question appears to be looking for a recommendation on a video player, so it is not on-topic and should be closed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 The question is partially asking for a video player but it also asking about a particular one with a problem. The question is on topic (but could use improvements) and the answer could be improved also. The answer should show how to use that player correctly, just not provide a link to it.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau That's why i would have voted to delete as the answer is link-only.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau fair enough.... there really wasn't a problem statement that I could extract from it as written, but if it can be rewritten to better illustrate the problem, then it would completely change my initial comment.

Comment: @psubsee2003 It ain't clearly stated but the middle part, with the play button, seems to indicate that the author wish help on that particular video player or how to use a better one. Now, I wouldn't be against closing as unclear what is being asked as if he just want a new video player, it is off-topic

Comment: Can anybody actually answer the question (ie: if you accidentally click the wrong review button: is there anything you can do about it?)

Answer (score 4):

The post was reviewed to delete 6 votes to 2. It was deleted on Sep 23 at 19:30. The post has been correctly handled.

As for your record, you cannot change this. Hitting the wrong button is a problem I've run into, unfortunately with audits.